# Scripted Jenkins pipeline: continue on fail

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to continue execution of the scripted pipeline even if the previous stage failed? I need to run specific commands (cleanup) when the build fails before the whole job fails.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022775/ignore-failure-in-pipeline-build-step

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The usual approach is to wrap your steps within a `try` block.

```java
try {
  sh "..."
} catch (err) {
  echo "something failed"
}
// cleanup
sh "rm -rf *"
```

To ease the pain and make the pipeline code more readable, I've encapsulated this in another method [here in my global library code](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/f62aa1851213efd6a31a8ab20411a3f532abfbe5/src/org/typo3/chefci/v1/Pipeline.groovy#L26-L50).

Another approach, esp. created because of this very issue, are the *declarative pipelines*  ([blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/09/19/blueocean-beta-declarative-pipeline-pipeline-editor/), [presentation](https://www.cloudbees.com/sites/default/files/2016-jenkins-world-introducing_a_new_way_to_define_jenkins_pipelines_1.pdf)).

Comment: Does it mean that if the build (sh "...") failed this step (try) will appear as success?

Comment: Hm - think that step is marked as success in this case, at least when using around an input step.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You could manually set the build to _FAILED_ (while continuing execution) using `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'`.

Comment: for those using declarative pipelines try https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to reflect that this was about good old scripted pipelines.

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer wouldn't fail the stage or even mark it as unstable. It is now possible to fail a stage, continue the execution of the pipeline and choose the result of the build:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, all stages will execute, the pipeline will be successful, but stage 2 will show as failed:

[image: Pipeline Example]

As you might have guessed, you can freely choose the `buildResult` and `stageResult`, in case you want it to be unstable or anything else. You can even fail the build and continue the execution of the pipeline.

Just make sure your Jenkins is up to date, since this is a fairly new feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
  post {
    always {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }
}
```

Will always cleanup the job even if the rest fails

Comment: Where do we find this? `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post'`

Comment: `post` is a part of the declarative pipeline. the OP asked about the scripted pipeline which is written using `node`. In that you would be able to use `try { ... } catch (e) { ... } finally { ... cleanup }`