# Jenkins: Ignore failure in pipeline build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

With jenkins build flow plugin this was possible:

```
ignore(FAILURE){
    build( "system-check-flow" )
}
```

How to do this with Declarative Pipeline syntax?

Answer (score 111):

To ignore a failed step in declarative pipeline you basically have two options:

1. Use `script` step and `try-catch` block (similar to previous proposition by R_K but in declarative style)

> ```
> stage('someStage') {
>     steps {
>         script {
>             try {
>                 build job: 'system-check-flow'
>             } catch (err) {
>                 echo err.getMessage()
>             }
>         }
>         echo currentBuild.result
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Use `catchError`

> ```
> stage('someStage') {
>     steps {
>         catchError {
>             build job: 'system-check-flow'
>         }
>         echo currentBuild.result
>     }
> }
> ```

In both cases the build won't be aborted upon exception in `build job: 'system-check-flow'`. In both cases the `echo` step (and any other following) will be executed.

But there's one **important difference** between these two options. In first case if the `try` section raises an exception the overall build status won't be changed (so `echo currentBuild.result` => `SUCCESS`). In the second case you overall build will fail (so `echo currentBuild.result` => `FAILURE`).

This is important, because you can always fail the overall build in first case (by setting `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'`) but you **can't** *repair* build in second option (`currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'` won't work).

Comment: catchError is now deprecated. Prefer try-catch

Comment: `catch (err) { echo err }`, provoke a error `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class hudson.AbortException`. Prefer `echo err.getMessage()`.

Comment: @lenkovi where did you read the catchError is deprecated? Can't find any such statement in the jenkins docu.

Comment: On a side node, you can use `catchError` also as a **stage option**. Comes in handy if you have multiple sub stages that you want to catch errors for in the parent stage. E. g. `stage('Test'){ options{ catchError(message: "Test failed", stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', buildResult: 'UNSTABLE') } stages { ... }}
`

Comment: @Jroger Thanks, I just suggested a fix for the answer!

Comment: I am doing currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' but jenkins is marking overall build as unstable. Any idea why?

Comment: One thing I found out here  was that if the try catch is wrapped in a multi parallel job, it only throws the first error. Anyway to capture and log all errors from a stage?

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for that tip. I was pulling my hair trying to figure out how to achieve this for stages that have nested sub stages. I couldn't find any mention of `catchError` being used this way in the jenkins docs, nor any stackoverflow post, but your solution works like a charm. Do you want to post it as an answer? I think it would make it a lot easier to find and many people would find it useful.

Comment: @Cnoor0171 I just [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74821467/7571258).

Answer (score 100):

In addition to simply making the stage pass, it is now also possible to fail the stage, but continue the pipeline and pass the build:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, all stages will execute, the pipeline will be successful, but stage 2 will show as failed:

[image: Pipeline Example]

As you might have guessed, you can freely choose the `buildResult` and `stageResult`, in case you want it to be unstable or anything else. You can even fail the build and continue the execution of the pipeline.

Just make sure your Jenkins is up to date, since this feature is only available since ["Pipeline: Basic Steps" 2.16 (May 14, 2019)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-basic-steps). Before that, `catchError` is still available but without parameters:

```
        steps {
            catchError {
                sh "exit 1"
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you know since what version this is available?

Comment: Great answer. Even better to use `catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE')`, so that the build is marked unstable instead of success or failure if any of the stages fail.

Answer (score 20):

I was looking for an answer for a long time and I found a hack for it! I put the try/catch block on the whole stage:

```
 try {
   stage('some-stage') {
         //do something
   }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    echo "Stage failed, but we continue"  
 }
 try {
   stage("some-other-stage") {  // do something }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    echo "Stage failed, but we still continue"
 }
```

As result you will get something like this:
[image]

This is still not ideal, but it gives the necessary results.

Comment: My use case was lots of independent builds that cannot run parallel due to a HW constraint, but must still all run even if 1st one fails. @Stacey I like your solution over the one where you catch all errors inside of the stage and ignore them by adding all bad stages to a long list and then "re-throwing" if any builds failed, right at the end. Because here, the bad stage still goes out of "scope" as failed. Mainly because it eliminates logic bugs in the re-throw code and any accidental bugs in the catch.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the following error on «try»: «WorkflowScript: Expected a stage».

Comment: Same, but @3Dark Unicorn's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

In recent versions it's possible to pass `propogate=false` option to build step.

**link:**
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

**example:**
`build job:"jobName", propagate:false`

Comment: Well, it's not about build step but rather whether to propagate faile from "jobName" to the build that has run it.

Answer (score 10):

Try this example:

```
stage('StageName1')
{
    steps
    {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')
        {
            SomeCodeThatCanBeErrored
        }
    }
}
stage('StageName2')
{
    steps
    {
        ContinueOtherCode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For my decalartive pipeline I have found another solution:

```
stage('Deploy test')
 {
  steps
   {      
    bat returnStatus: true, script: 'sc stop Tomcat9'
    // The return value of the step will be the status code!
    // evaluate return status yourself, or ignore it
   }
 }
```

The same works for the sh command to execute scripts on Unix platforms.

The example ignores the return status, because the tomcat might be already stopped, because of a previously failed pipeline run.

Answer (score 5):

Complementing the existing working solutions that use `catchError` as a [step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56975233/7571258) or in [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68831194/7571258), you can also use `catchError` as a **stage option**.

This is useful if you have multiple sub stages that you want to catch errors for in the parent stage:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Tests') {
            options { 
                catchError(message: "Test failed", stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', buildResult: 'UNSTABLE') 
            } 
            stages {
                stage('Test 1') {
                    echo 'test 1 succeeded'
                }        
                stage('Test 2') {
                    error 'test 2 failed'
                }        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't explicitly [documented](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options), but there is a hint that you may use steps as options (emphasis mine):

> However, the stage-level options can only contain **steps like** retry,
> timeout, or timestamps, or Declarative options that are relevant to a
> stage, like skipDefaultCheckout.

It names a few steps as examples, but not as the only possible steps to be used as options. Also, if you enter an invalid option, Jenkins lists all available options in the error message, which includes `catchError`.

Answer (score 3):

In the new pipeline, you can use try-catch to achieve this.

```
node{
   try{
      build job: 'system-check-flow'
   }    
   catch (err){
      echo "system-check-flow failed"
   }
   try{
      build job: 'job2'
   }    
   catch (err){
      echo "job2 failed"
   }
}
```

Here it will build the 'system-check-flow' job. If it fails it will catch the error, ignore, and then move on to build 'job2'

Comment: While this looks like it'll work, it isn't built using declarative pipeline syntax.

Comment: @Sven this is not a problem though - you can wrap `try{}..catch(){}` in a `script{}` block, for this to work in the declarative syntax

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest and latest way would be:

```
stage('Integration Tests') {
    steps {
        script {
            warnError(message: "${STAGE_NAME} stage was unstable.", catchInterruptions: false) {
                // your scripts   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#warnerror-catch-error-and-set-build-and-stage-result-to-unstable

Answer (score 2):

See [this post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/07/05/jenkins-pipeline-stage-result-visualization-improvements/) for a full discussion.

Answer (score 2):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
                stage('Stage') {
                    steps{
                        script{
                            jobresult = build(job: './failing-job',propagate:false).result
                            if(jobresult != 'SUCCESS'){
                                catchError(stageResult: jobresult, buildResult: 'UNSTABLE'){
                                    error("Downstream job failing-job failed.")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

For all those that are wondering about how to set the result of a downstream job to the stage/build) Not the most graceful solution, but it gets the job done. Funny thing is that if this stageResult variable was available as a global variable or as a variable outside the catchError block these kinds of solutions would not be needed. Sadly it isn't, and the only way to set the stage result in a pipeline that I thought of is this way. The error() block is needed, otherwise catchError will not set the stageResult/buildResult(the catchError block requires an error, ofcourse).

Answer (score 0):

you could put the step script inside "post" step, if if it's a teardown like step

code as below:

```
    post {
    always {
        script {
            try{
                echo 'put your alway need run scripts here....if it's a teardown like step'
            }catch (err) {
                echo 'here failed'
        }
        script{
            emailext (
                xxxx
            )
        }
    }
```