# Jenkins declarative pipeline - proceed to subsequent stages even one stage fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have below stage and when it fails, the stage has to be "Paused" for user to take required action to fix the issue at the back end server. After fixing the issue, when user click OK in the input message, the next stage would be executed. But in the below code, when i click OK in the input message box the whole job is terminated. Any idea how to achieve this?

Appreciate your help!

```groovy
stage('Execute Shellscript')
{   
    steps 
    {
        script
        {
            try
            {
                def var1 = sshCommand remote: remote, command: "sh fastartstop.sh"
                sleep(time:30,unit:"SECONDS")   
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {   
                currentBuild.result ='UNSTABLE'
                echo "The current status is ${currentBuild.result}"
                echo "Failed: ${e}"
                env.RELEASE_SCOPE = input message: 'Job failed. Please fix it manually and proceed further. Else click Abort to terminate the job!!!', ok: 'Proceed'  

                emailext (body: "", 
                    subject: "HOST ${params.FA_HOST} - FA Patching fails at ${env.STAGE_NAME} stage and refer Job ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} for more info. Please fix the issue manually and proceed further for next step!!",
                    to: "${params.EMAIL_LIST}")
            }        
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022775/ignore-failure-in-pipeline-build-step ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore failure in pipeline build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022775/ignore-failure-in-pipeline-build-step)