# Jenkins: Catch error to skip to next stage, but still show errored stage has failed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am currently using Jenkins [`catchError`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) to catch if an error has occurred within a stage, and if so, then skip to the next stage.

What I would like is to present that if a stage had caught an error, to presented in Jenkins as **Red** (**Failed**), even though this stage was skipped to the next.

This is how Jenkins pipeline stage is coded to catch error is script fails:

```
    stage('test_run') {
        steps {
            catchError {
                sh """#!/bin/bash -l
                    ***

                    npm run test:run:reporter
                """
            }
        }
    }
```

I found this solution in StackOverflow:
[Jenkins: Ignore failure in pipeline build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022775/jenkins-ignore-failure-in-pipeline-build-step)

This solution works, but in Jenkins' run, the stage that failed is presenting **Green** (aka **Success**).

This Jenkins run indicates that it failed:

[image: Failed Jenkins Run]

The following stage actually the cause of the failure and was skipped on caught error, however, **this stage is showing Green (Success) and prefer to present it to be Red (Failed)**:

[image: Failed stage skipped showing Green Success]

The final **post** actions is showing as **Yellow** (**Unstable**), when normally it shows as **Green** (**Success**):

[image: Unstable]

Thank you for reading, always appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DashrathMundkar Thank you

Using [catchError()](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/) with the **buildResult** and **stageResult**, however I set the values to both 'FAILURE', and that did the trick.

```
catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE', message: 'Test Suite had a failure') { }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
  Add your commands
}
```

Add whatever result you want to set for build and stage result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, giving this a try

Comment: Almost but not quite: The stage wrapped with `catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {***}`, the failed stage did present as **Red (Failure)** (good), however, the overall Jenkins job final status is **Uncertain (Yellow)** (bad). When using `catchError {***}`, the failed stage presented as **Green (Success)** (bad) and  the overall Jenkins job final status is **Red (Failure)** (good).

Comment: I was curious why `buildResult: 'SUCCESS'` would trigger **Uncertain**. "if an error is caught, the overall build result will be set to this value. Note that the build result can only get worse, so you cannot change the result to SUCCESS if the current result is UNSTABLE or worse. Use SUCCESS or null to keep the build result from being set when an error is caught."