# Error handling in Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkinsfile, I have the below stages running in parallel under UnitTest stage:

```
UnitTests-Stage1, UnitTests-Stage2 , UnitTests-Stage3
```

And then we have "Analysis" stage that runs after UnitTest

If any of the stages ( UnitTests-Stage1, UnitTests-Stage2, UnitTests-Stage3) fails under UnitTest then the rest of the parallel stages should run but the parent stage (UnitTest) should be marked as failed (red) and the next stage which is "Analysis" should be skipped.

I have tried catchError and try/catch but even if there is an error the stage still shows as green.

Below is the jenkins file

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-lib')_

pipeline {
  agent none


  stages {
    stage('init') {


      agent {
        label 'jenkins-01'
      }
        steps {
            script {

              //code for loading env and scripts
            }
        }
    }

    stage('UnitTests') {

        parallel {
            stage('UnitTest-Stage1') {
              agent {
                label 'jenkins-01'
              }

              steps {
                script {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                try {
                unitTest.function1()
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
               }
              }
            }
              post {
              success {
              script {
                notifyTeams()
              }
              }
              failure {
                script {
                  errMsg = caughtException.message
                  notifyTeams()
                }
              }
              }
            }

          stage('UnitTest-Stage2') {
            agent {
              label 'jenkins-2'
            }
            steps {
              script {
                try {
                unitTest.function3()
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
              }
            }
            post {
              success {
                 script{
                  notifyTeams()
                 }
              }
              failure {
              script{
                  errMsg = caughtException.message
                  notifyTeams()
              }
              }
            }
     }

        stage('UnitTest-Stage3') {
            agent {
              label 'jenkins-1'
            }
            steps {
              script {
                try {
                unitTest.function4()
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
              }
            }
            post {
              success {
                 script{
                  notifyTeams()
                 }
              }
              failure {
              script{
                  errMsg = caughtException.message
                  notifyTeams()
              }
              }
            }
        }
        }

        post {
        success {
              script {
              notifyTeams()
              }
        }
        failure {
              script {
              errMsg = caughtException.message
              notifyTeams()
              if (caughtException) {
                        error caughtException.message
               }
              }
        }
        }
    }

 stage('Analysis') {

      parallel {
        stage('Analysis-Stage1') {

          steps {
            script {
              try {
                sq.function1()
              }

          catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
          }
            }
          }
          post {
            // always {
            //cleanWs()
            // }
            success {
              script {
                notifyTeams()
              }
            }
            failure {
              script {
                  errMsg = caughtException.message
                  notifyTeams()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [catch error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66705084/3730626) to change the result of the stage instead of `try... catch`.

Comment: I tried that. But I also want to catch the exception and show in email/msteams which I am unable to do using catchError

Comment: Combination of try..catch and catchError seems to have fixed the issue.